# SQL yyyymm date formatting

Tags: sql, date, time, split

I have a month column in YYYYMM-Example 201204 format and I need to break it into two column year(2012) and month(04)????

I've tried using Ltrim & Rtrim to break apart but not really working.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Try DATEPART(year, date) and DATEPART(month, date) (mssql)

Comment: `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` are for removing spaces from the ends of a string. Did you mean `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, which return left and right substrings?

Comment: Is the column a VARCHAR/CHAR column, or an INT column? Because parsing a VARCHAR/CHAR column is very different from parsing an INT column.

Answer (score 0):

This requires string manipulations, which differ by database.  A typical method is:

```
select substr(col, 1, 4) as yyyy, substr(col, 5, 2) as mm
```

In some databases, the function would be `substring()`.  Most databases support either `substr()` or `substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select yyyy = datepart( year  , t.datetime_column ) ,
       mm   = datepart( month , t.datetime_column ) ,
       ...
from dbo.some_table t
```

Or

```
select yyyy = year(  t.datetime_column ) ,
       mm   = month( t.datetime_column ) ,
       ...
from dbo.some_table t
```

Or, if the column is a string:

```
select yyyy = convert(int, left(  t.some_column , 4 ) ) ,
       mm   = convert(int, right( t.some_column , 2 ) ) ,
       ...
from dbo.some_table t
where t.some_column like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Oracle (since none is specified) and varchar/char this would be another option:

```
select 
    extract(year from (to_date('201204', 'yyyymm'))) year, 
    extract(month from (to_date('201204', 'yyyymm'))) month 
from dual;
```

First, convert to date and then get the month and year using extract function. Assumes month is always two chars and year four.